# Error while running Discord.JS bot

Tags: discord.js

When I am trying to start my Discord.JS BOT, it shows up this error:

> root@Gabitzuu-Teo:/home/5times# node bot
>   module.js:538
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './packets/WebSocketPacketManager'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (/home/5times/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:5:23)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
>   root@Gabitzuu-Teo:/home/5times#

(5times - my BOT's name.)
Does MySQL break it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could provide us with your code.
It  appears you're missing a module

`Error: Cannot find module './packets/WebSocketPacketManager'`

If you navigate to your bots folder in your terminal you can then type `npm install` into your terminal and it should install all dependancies listed in your package.json